# group by and display contents of last row for each result

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I've got some data of two objects and I want to retrieve the last row of both the objects, preferably in one query.

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE data
(
  pid serial NOT NULL,
  dt timestamp without time zone,
  object_id integer,
  info_1 numeric(10,8),
  speed numeric,
  CONSTRAINT dat_pid PRIMARY KEY (pid)
)
```

Sample data:

```
1, 2014-04-29 12:02:56, 8, ....
2, 2014-04-29 12:02:10, 8, ....
3, 2014-04-29 12:01:02, 8, ....
5, 2014-04-29 12:01:32, 6, ....
.....
```

I want a row per unique object ID, each row being the newest one available. I tried to achieve it by using this query, but it wants pid to be in the group by clause. But I don't want to group by the PID, but at the tracker id....

```
SELECT * 
FROM data
GROUP BY object_id
```

Comment: [This related answer on SO should be of help.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use **[`DISTINCT ON`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)** for this type of queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (object_id) *
FROM data
ORDER BY object_id, dt DESC ;
```

Comment: This is exactly was I was searching for. For me it was `select distinct on (col1) * from f order by col1, timestamp DESC;`